# Joining two list together into one without repeating

Tags: python, list, matrix

how would I join 2 lists together?

Lets say:

```
list1 = ['hi', 'state', 'California', 'usa']
list2 = ['moon', 'sun', 'hi', 'flower']
```

and the output would join the words together , excluding words that would contain the same word twice like 'hi hi' like this:

```
['hi moon', 'hi sun', ' hi flower', 'state moon', 'state hi', 'state flower'] ...eetc..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate each list in a list comprehension. `product` isn't really needed in this case:

```
>>> list1 = ['hi', 'state', 'California', 'usa']
>>> list2 = ['moon', 'sun', 'hi', 'flower']
>>> [a+' '+b for a in list1 for b in list2 if a != b]
['hi moon', 'hi sun', 'hi flower', 'state moon', 'state sun', 'state hi', 'state flower', 'California moon', 'California sun', 'California hi', 'California flower', 'usa moon', 'usa sun', 'usa hi', 'usa flower']
```

This is equivalent to the longer form:

```
>>> L = []
>>> for a in list1:
...     for b in list2:
...         if a != b:
...             L.append(a+' '+b)
...             
>>> L
['hi moon', 'hi sun', 'hi flower', 'state moon', 'state sun', 'state hi', 'state flower', 'California moon', 'California sun', 'California hi', 'California flower', 'usa moon', 'usa sun', 'usa hi', 'usa flower']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and then filter out any pairs that are equal:

```
from itertools import product

[' '.join([a, b]) for a, b in product(list1, list2) if a != b]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list1 = ['hi', 'state', 'California', 'usa']
>>> list2 = ['moon', 'sun', 'hi', 'flower']
>>> [' '.join([a, b]) for a, b in product(list1, list2) if a != b]
['hi moon', 'hi sun', 'hi flower', 'state moon', 'state sun', 'state hi', 'state flower', 'California moon', 'California sun', 'California hi', 'California flower', 'usa moon', 'usa sun', 'usa hi', 'usa flower']
>>> pprint(_)
['hi moon',
 'hi sun',
 'hi flower',
 'state moon',
 'state sun',
 'state hi',
 'state flower',
 'California moon',
 'California sun',
 'California hi',
 'California flower',
 'usa moon',
 'usa sun',
 'usa hi',
 'usa flower']
```